# how to return default view from action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have two views which consist same login form. The forms call same action. i want to display error in page. i redirect to indexpage. But when i login from loginpage error is dispalyed in indexpage but i want the error to display in loginpage when login from login page and in index page when login from index page

my code is

```
public ActionResult ValidateLogIn(UserLogin users)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = _accountUserService.GetAccountUserByEmailId(users.Email);
            if (result != null)
            {
                if (result.Password == users.Password && result.Active)
                {
                    Session.Add("Username", result.Email);
                    ViewBag.email = users.Email;
                    return View("Index");
                    //return full form registration;    
                }
                ViewBag.UError = NcMessage.NotAcitvated;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.UError = NcMessage.UsernameNotFound;
            }
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

how could i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Just Need to change last line to return `login` view

```
public ActionResult ValidateLogIn(UserLogin users)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = _accountUserService.GetAccountUserByEmailId(users.Email);
            if (result != null)
            {
                if (result.Password == users.Password && result.Active)
                {
                    Session.Add("Username", result.Email);
                    ViewBag.email = users.Email;
                    return View("Index");
                    //return full form registration;    
                }
                ViewBag.UError = NcMessage.NotAcitvated;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.UError = NcMessage.UsernameNotFound;
            }
        }
        return View("Login");
      // Return to Login page as  Authentication is unsuccessful or ModelState is Invalid
    }
```